# Credit, as in Ansehen, Gutschreiben

Tags: verb, idiom

How would I say "She credits you all the time," in the sense of her giving you the credit, acknowledgement for something? It wouldn't be "Sie schreibt dir immer gut"
would it be?

Answer (score 2):

> Sie zollt dir immer Annerkennung.  Sie macht dir ständig alle Ehre.

Somewhat less intensive:

> Sie erwähnt dich ständig.

"Gutschreiben" means rather something financial, z.B. etwas überweisen.

Answer (score 0):

Use the verb **zuschreiben**.

*She credits you all the time.*

> Sie schreibt das immer dir zu.

This can be meant both positive and negative:

> Vor Jahren noch schrieb man ihren Erfolg allein ihrer Mutter zu.